# AND/OR where clause logic confusion

Tags: sql, where-clause, logical-operators

So I have this table for customers with Main and Mobile phones. I either have a valid number or a blank space or a value of NULL.

```
CustName   MainPhone     MobilePhone
Joe        800-111-1234  321-123-1234
Jack                     321-321-1237  
Jill                     
Jimmy      321-123-1234  
James      NULL          432-322-2222
```

So I have 5 records in total and I want to filter out CustNames that have a blank on both Main and Mobile. So I checked first to see how many I had and used this WHERE CLAUSE:

```
Select *
From MyTable
Where (MainPhone = '' and MobilePhone = '')
```

and yes this returned one record only, in this case Jill which has no numbers in either fields.

Now if I want to list everyone except the records that have a blankspace on both MainPhone and MobilePhone what would the WHERE CLAUSE look like? I've tried a few variations and I'm not getting the proper results.

The Final resultset should be like this

```
CustName   MainPhone     MobilePhone
Joe        800-111-1234  321-123-1234
Jack                     321-321-1237  
Jimmy      321-123-1234  
James      NULL          432-322-2222
```

Thanks

Comment: you mean? `Where (MainPhone != '' and MobilePhone !='') `

Comment: you mean `Where (MainPhone != '' OR MobilePhone !='')` which comes from simply inverting the first query : `Where NOT (MainPhone = '' and MobilePhone = '')` and applying De morgan.

Comment: You added the varchar "EmptySpace" as the value in your database?

Comment: @jENN, no the emptyspace is not a value it was just saying this value is a blank space. I've edited my post to make it less confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this query

```
Select *
From mytable
Where (MainPhone != '' AND MainPhone IS NOT NULL) OR (MobilePhone != '' AND MobilePhone IS NOT NULL)
```

fiddle for the same

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5e668/2

Comment: I was leaving out the IS NULL part on both main and mobile which dropped off the good records ... thanks for pointing this out :-)

Answer (score 0):

```html
Select *
From MyTable
Where (ISNULL(MainPhone, '') = '' and ISNULL(MobilePhone, '') = '')
```